Show that $1105$ is the smallest hypothenuse for which four distinct primitive Pythagorean triples exist

Show that $c := 1105$ is the smallest integer for which there exist four distinct primitive Pythagorean triples with this hypothenuse.

I know Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares and the parametrisation of primitive Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ via $\pm a = 2rs, \pm b = r^2-s^2$ and $\pm c = r^2+s^2$ for $r,s$ coprime and exactly one of the odd. With said parametrisation it is easy to see that indeed $1105$ corresponds to four distinct triples, but I do not see a way other than brute force to argue that it is the smallest number to do so.

Hint 1: Have you noticed that where the hypotenuse gives triples, the number of primitive triples for that hypotenuse is a power of 2?

It might have something to do with its factorization: $1105=5(13)(17)=(2^2+1^2)(3^2+2^2)(4^2+1^2)$

I have edited my answer below to include more intuitive evidence that your conjecture is true.

As Mike said, this is related to prime factors $\equiv1\pmod4$. $5,13,17$ are the three smallest such primes. The relation to (primitive) Pythagorean triples comes from their factorization in the ring of Gaussian integers. For example
$$(2+i)(3+2i)(4+i)=9+32i$$ yields $r=9, s=32$,  whereas
$$(2+i)(3+2i)(4-i)=23+24i$$ gives $r=23, s=24$ et cetera.

The number of "primitive" triples for any side of a Pythagorean triple is $\,2^{n-1},\,$ where $\,n\,$ is the number of unique prime factors of that side length. There may be more imprimitives than this but not primitives.
In the case of $\,1105=5\cdot13\cdot17,\,$ there should be  $\,2^{3-1}=4\,$ such primitives. But, how do we prove that $\,1105\,$ is the smallest hypotenuse with $\,4\,$ primitives?
The OEIS listing here shows the first "few" hypotenuse values and shows which ones have more than one corresponding primitive triple. It does not extend far enough but, testing possible hypotenuse values of the form $\,C=4x+1,\,$ we can find those that are valid for Pythagorean triples and how many triples there for those hypotenuse values of $\,5,13,17,25,\cdots,1105\,$  etc. We don't have to do that however because we can see from the list that
$\,5\cdot13=65\,$ and $\,65\,$ has two primitive triples;  $\,5\cdot17=85\,$ and $\,85\,$ has two primitive triples;
$\,5\cdot29=145\,$ and $\,145\,$ has two primitive triples;
Since $\,1105\,$ is the product of the three smallest prime numbers of the form $\,4x+1,\,$ it should have four corresponding primitives by the reasoning above and, it does as shown by the test below where a defined range of $\,m$-values is tested to see which if any yield integers for a $\,k$-value.
Matching side C where $C=m^2+k^2$
$$C=m^2+k^2\implies k=\sqrt{C-m^2}\\
  \qquad\text{for}\qquad \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2C-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \lfloor\sqrt{C-1}\rfloor$$
The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$C=1105\implies \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2210-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=24 \le m \le \lfloor\sqrt{1105-1}\rfloor=33\quad \\
\land \quad m\in\{24,31,32,33\}\Rightarrow k\in\{23,12,9,4\}\\$$
$$f(24,23)=(47,1104,1105)\qquad f(31,12)=(817,744,1105)\qquad 
f(32,9)=(943,576,1105)\qquad f(33,4)=(1073,264,1105)\qquad$$
